# How can I prevent an absolute div from showing on mobile?

Tags: html, mobile

I have a div box with an absolute position fixed to the left side of a page.  It looks great on PC's and is doing its job of being unobtrusive to the user.  However, when the page is loaded from a mobile device, the left side of the screen is no longer way off to the side, it is on the edge of the content so this absolute box now covers a little bit of the content on the left.  My goal is to only show this one specific div box to PC's, while preventing it from loading on mobile devices.
CSS:

```
.harry {
float: left;
padding: 5px 0 0 0;
margin: 0;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 100px;
z-index: 999999;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="harry">

<big><p><a href="javascript:popup('Logical Position has served over 250,000,000 impressions on Google, Yahoo!, Bing and Facebook for thousands of clients in the United States, Canada, Mexico and Europe!');"><img src="images/side-harry.png" height=200 /></a>    </p></big>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to just set a CSS3 media query, and hide that div when a mobile device is detected:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .harry {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly (except I increased 480px to 800px to make sure it doesn't show on high rez phones/tablets)